# QtDesigner layouts not stretching (preview different from GUI)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have made the following layout in QtDesigner 5.6.2, which looks fine in the QtDesigner GUI:

[image: qt-designer-OK]

Basically, I want the buttons to be as wide as the text (plus margins), vertically they should expand as much as possible - but they should stick to the left.

The remaining space should be a horizontal layout hosting several sliders, and as is typical for a horizontal layout, they would be "evenly spaced" horizontally.

But when I hit Form/Preview... in the app (or also with the sample .py code below), I get this:

[image: preview-bad]

Basically, everything is "compressed" in center, and I do not get why this is?

How can I get the preview to be the same as in QtDesigner?

`test1.ui`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>579</width>
    <height>332</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout" stretch="0,1">
      <item>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Minimum">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Minimum">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_2">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_3">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_4">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_5">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>579</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

`test1.py`

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('test1.ui', self)
    self.show()

def main():
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = MyMainWindow()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Preview is not necessarily going to be the same as the design since in the Preview the elements interact. The solution is also to make the QSliders expand horizontally by changing the horizontal sizePolicy to "Minimum":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>579</width>
    <height>332</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout" stretch="0,1">
      <item>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Minimum">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Minimum">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushButton</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_2">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_3">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_4">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider_5">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QSlider" name="verticalSlider">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>579</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Many thanks for that - horizontal policy to minimum does work, but it makes the slider heads massive ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLEKO.png ). It seems, once we get to `horizontalLayout_2` which hosts the sliders, in QtDesigner it gets a width calculated based on the window size and other widgets, and so with that width, the sliders can be positioned "evenly" - but in preview/pyqt5, that width is gone. Only alternative I could find was adding horizontal spacers, as in: hspacer- vslider-hspacer-...-vslider-hspacer - then I get the layout as I want it (but I hoped to avoid adding spacers).